# Getting not supported media type error

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

Hi i am using Rest client i.e Postman to send the REST request but getting error :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1432829209385,
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
    "message": "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/api/v1/user"
}
```

My controller is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json")
    public Map<String,Object> updateUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
//      userService.updateUser(user);
        return ResponseHandler.generateResponse("", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED, false, null);
    }
```

I am sending the request as shown in picture via REST client.

[image]

Answer (score 65):

Change your `Content-Type` in Postman to `application/json`. Click on the **Headers** button to do so.

Also you are not producing json in the method. Remove the `produces="application/json"` from the annotation

Comment: You mean, change the `Accept` header.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue, and resolved it in a different way.

Newer versions of Postman have options in the "Body" section.  If "raw" is chosen, then there is a drop down where "JSON (application/json)" works.

[image: POST Body raw : JSON]

Answer (score 5):

Under Headers in Postman app, type a Key as `Content-Type` and set the value as `application\json`.

[image]